# MATLAB's svmtrain : save support vector indexes instead of support vectors themselves

Tags: matlab, memory, machine-learning, svm

I'm working on a machine learning problem which requires me to use multiple support vector machines. It works relatively well; however, the problem is that the number of support vector machines for each SVM tends to be large (~2,000), and the number of input features is on the order of 50,000. I need about a 100 SVMs.

Running this on my laptop quickly exhausts all of the available memory; I think this is because `svmtrain` creates an SVM which saves (i.e. has another copy) of all the support vectors. Since I'm keeping the original training data around, I was wondering if there was a way to instruct it to save indexes to these support vectors instead, which would use much less memory? Or another way to reduce the amount of memory it needs per SVM?

Comment: I dont know the exact solution to your problem but can suggest an alternative. Once your svm is trained and used and is no longer required you can free its memory by calling "clear". This way freed memory can be allocated to training and storing next instance of svm. This way computer will not store any unnecessary data.

Comment: @MohitJain: yes, of course, but I need to keep the SVMs around (they have to all be used together)

Answer (score 0):

`svmtrain` creates `SVMStruct` object, which stores the indices of support vectors in `SupportVectorIndices` field. So simply store this variable's values in some container and free the rest of the model.

Accodring to [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html#outputarg_SVMStruct)

> SupportVectorIndices — Vector of indices that specify the rows in Training, the training data, that were selected as support vectors after the data was normalized, according to the AutoScale argument.

Comment: Thanks, though if I do this, is there a way to quickly recreate the SVMStruct from the indexes?